# Verify if this set of matrices span $M_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have the set:

$$S = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 2\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$
And I want to verify if it spans $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ (the space of all 2x2 matrices).

1) If I verify this set is linearly independent, and knowing dim $M_2(\mathbb{R}) = 4$, is it okay to say that $S$ is a basis for $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ because it is linearly independent and has 4 vectors? I can verify if my set is L.I. and has $n$ vectors, then it spans the space of dimension $n$ formed by that vectors?

2) I think i've read somewhere that if I check that the set is L.I. and then write each vector of $S$ as a linear combination of the canonical basis for $M_2(\mathbb{R})$, then S is a set that spans $M_2(\mathbb{R})$. Why this is true? Can somebody give me an explanation of why this works? Because, for me, any vector in any set could be written as a linear combination of the canonical basis...

Comment: 1) yes and yes again
2) I think it's presumably the other way around: if you can write any element of the canonical basis via your set of vectors *then* you know that these vectors must span the whole space. Clearly if their number is equal to the dimension of the space, then these must be L.I, i.e. a basis.

Comment: It is possible to simplify (2) if we know the dimension of the vector space, for which a basis is sought.  Here you probably know, from the mention of a "standard basis", that $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is dimension four (over the reals).  So it would suffice to show the linear independence OR spanning property of a set of four vectors, to prove that a basis.